# How to add javascript to superset chart?

Tags: javascript, apache-superset

I am new to Superset. I've created a map chart to display specific paths on the map. Now, I want to add some additional features. When I hover over the path, I would like to display the city name when the mouse hovers over a point. How can I achieve this? In my database, I have longitude and latitude values for specific locations on the path, along with the corresponding city names.

There is a field as "javascript onclick href". but i unable to access that field

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I do not have any codes to provide.  i just use deck.gl Scatterplot to plot points on map